# Click on element of a dynamic loaded page using Selenium WebDriver java

Tags: java, javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to click on particular element of an dynamically loaded page.Web element generated when  we scroll the page.It similar like an jabong webpage.

I try to do that on jabong webpage this is my code

```
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.navigate().to("http://www.jabong.com/men/clothing/"
            + "?source=topnav");


    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    System.out.println("Close the modal popup");
    driver.findElement(By.id("jab-vchr-cls")).click();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

      /**
       * while(true) loop is required to search the 
       * element until element found.We put find
       * element within try-catch and if it get 
       * exception it scroll the page and again 
       * try to find the element.
       */
    while(true) {

            ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,100)", "");
        try {
            WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='http:    //static3.jassets.com/p/The-Indian-Garage-Co.-Checks-Red-Casual-Shirt-2889-679124-1-catalog.jpg']/img"));
            Wait<WebDriver> wait_element=new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
            wait_element.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element));
            element.click();
            System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!At Last Get Success!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
            break;

        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
        }
```

}
}

My question is

1.Is there any better way to do this things?

2.How to make this script faster?

Comment: there is **certainly** a better way to do this.. You should never have to use an infinite loop for something like this.

Comment: @sircapsalot thanks for your reply i think for this loop but i did not find any other way to scroll the page and loading the element to find the desired one.So I use break to stop this loop when find the desired element.Do you have any better idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this way if you want to avoid while(true) though I donot think there is any problem with this loop.

```
    boolean reachedbottom = Boolean.parseBoolean(js.executeScript("return $(document).height() == ($(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop());").toString());

    while (!reachedbottom) {
        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,600)", "");
        try {
            reachedbottom=Boolean.parseBoolean(js.executeScript("return $(document).height() == ($(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop());").toString());
            WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='http://static3.jassets.com/p/The-Indian-Garage-Co.-Checks-Red-Casual-Shirt-2889-679124-1-catalog.jpg']/img"));
            Wait<WebDriver> wait_element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
            wait_element.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element));
            element.click();
            System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!At Last Get Success!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
            break;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. In the [Getting Started with Selenium](http://github.com/ddavison/getting-started-with-selenium) framework, the `AutomationTest#waitForElement` method is a great way to handle things.  It's an alternative to the webdriver wait, but works all the same.

   ```
   /**
    * Private method that acts as an arbiter of implicit timeouts of sorts.. sort of like a Wait For Ajax method.
    */
   private WebElement waitForElement(By by) {
       int attempts = 0;
       int size = driver.findElements(by).size();

       while (size == 0) {
           size = driver.findElements(by).size();
           if (attempts == MAX_ATTEMPTS) fail(String.format("Could not find %s after %d seconds",
                                                            by.toString(),
                                                            MAX_ATTEMPTS));
           attempts++;
           try {
               Thread.sleep(1000); // sleep for 1 second.
           } catch (Exception x) {
               fail("Failed due to an exception during Thread.sleep!");
               x.printStackTrace();
           }
       }

       if (size > 1) System.err.println("WARN: There are more than 1 " + by.toString() + " 's!");

       return driver.findElement(by);
   }
   ```
2. You can take it out of the infinite loop.  If a page doesn't load something within 10 seconds then i'd say it's an app issue that needs to be rectified.  Take it out out of the infinite loop, and using something like `waitForElement` specified above, or just use a `WebDriverWait` class.

Furthermore, you shouldn't ever have to scroll to an element. I still have yet to find a reason to do something like this.  As long as the element is on the DOM, it should be able to be operated on.

Comment: thanks for your kind reply with helpful code.
1.I want to know that is it really app issue because if net was slow?
2.Actually 6000 or more element will be loaded when page scroll down it is as per lazy loading feature.So I need to implement this loop.Do you want to say that if i not implement this loop and find the element it can find the element?
Actually I am new on this so this may be some childish question.

Comment: @sircapsalot is there any difference between while(true) ...... break and while(size==0) because this two thing do the same work.another thing I want to mention that if element was not located then it got exception not get the size.

Comment: well no, but if you look at the loop closer, it only tries a certain amount of times.  whatever `MAX_ATTEMPTS` is set to.  Usually 5.  so technically it will only be 5 seconds.   Doing the exact same thing as `WebDriverWait.until(present(something), 5)` [pseudo-code]